# ffmpeg gives error DTS out of order and Non-monotonous DTS in output stream

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I'm trying to concatenate multiple mp4 videos into one using ffmpeg. The "how to" for this is mostly identical across the web:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i inputfile.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

But when I try to concatenate my files, I keep getting output like the following:

```
[concat @ 0x1f72560] DTS 3815 < 3812809 out of order
[mp4 @ 0x20ad2e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 3812809, current: 3815; changing to 3812810. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

The result is that I have a file where the audio and video work for the first segment, but only the audio works for subsequent segments. Occasionally, I'll get a video with no audio.

Some users switch to MP4Box, but I've tried MP4Box with the same results. What am I missing? I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691943/ffmpeg-concat-poduces-dts-out-of-order-errors) that says `-c copy` is the problem, but I don't really follow what it's saying about reencoding or why that's necessary.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i test.txt -c copy test.mp4 &> result.txt
```

Contents of `test.txt`

```
file '/raw/01 - Introduction.mp4'
file '/raw/02 - Background Material.mp4'
```

Contents of `result.txt`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12101801/

Comment: Your version of ffmpeg (2.5.8) is rather old, could you try with one of the latest ?
If you're on windows, http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/, otherwise compile it from the latest download : https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Also, could you post the output for each separate videos ? Just to check if they both have the same codecs and properties.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. I originally installed ffmpeg with `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`. It sounds like I need to do a fresh install, but I'm not completely following the instructions here: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media. It's not clear to me at all what I'm supposed to do to compile from source.

Comment: Installed latest version using instructions here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu. New output still gives `DTS 3815 < 3812809 out of order`, but not `Non-monotonous DTS`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12122000/. Resulting video has both sets of audio, but only the first video.

Comment: Output for first video (using `ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12122014/

Comment: output for second video: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12122016/

Comment: Should clarify that I ran Ran `ffmpeg -f concat -i test.txt -c:v h264 -c:a mp3 test.mp4 &> result.txt` this time, not `-c copy`, as `-c copy` still gives `Non-monotonous DTS` error.

Comment: The reason the copy is failing is probably because your two videos have different framerate (30 vs 29.97). When concatenating two or more videos, you must make sure they share the same properties (same codecs, same framerate, etc..). You can try remuxing one of your videos to get the same fps as the other one (ffmpeg won't do that, try mkvmerge or something), don't forget to slow/speed the audio too, and then try again to concat :/ .

Comment: That sucks... This was just a test of two videos. I've got a few dozen collections of anywhere between a few and over a dozen videos that need to be concatenated. Surely there's already a program/script that can analyze the various video properties, remux, and concat. I used Any Video Converter on Windows, but that's basically the only reason I fire up my Windows machine anymore. I'd like to find a replacement on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but one of the dozen threads I read when facing an issue with two similar mp4 files unable to be concatenated. The videos themselves were created by overlaying an audio file on a static image.

After several hours, through ffprobe I identified my audio files had different sampling rates (some were 48KHz and others 44.1 KHz). I had to use the -ar attribute to get them resampled. The video now seems to get concatenated correctly.